# Spring data mongodb sort by division of two fields

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

```
@Document
class RequestEntity {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String categoryCode;
  private Double sourceAmount;
  private Double targetAmount;

  // getters, setters
}
```

I need a list of RequestEntity `where categoryCode='X'` and sort result by `sourceAmount/targetAmount desc`.

Any `@Query` or `mongoTemplate` example would be appreciated.

I looked too many examples but I couldn't find any example for returning just a sorted list of collection itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it by having more search, may help someone else.

```
public List<RequestEntity> findBestBuyings(String categoryCode) {

    Aggregation aggregation =
        newAggregation(
            RequestEntity.class,
            match(Criteria.where("categoryCode").is(categoryCode)),
            project(TenderEntity.class).and(ArithmeticOperators.Divide.valueOf("sourceAmount").divideBy("targetAmount")).as("rate"),
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "rate"));

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, RequestEntity.class, RequestEntity.class).getMappedResults();
}
```